# How to increase md-tab size in angular-material?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I want to increase my tab width like shown in below image,but not sure how to do this in angular-material.

Please help
[image]

Comment: Can you share the related code ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check all options for `md-tabs` in the official doc [md-tabs doc](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/api/directive/mdTabs).

```
md-stretch-tabs mobile      desktop
auto            stretched   ---
always          stretched   stretched
never           ---         ---

<md-tabs md-stretch-tabs="always">
  <md-tab label="Tab #1"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab #2"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab #3"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

**In Angular Material version 6.0.1**

```
<mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs="always">
  <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Doc Angular Material - Tabs](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/api/directive/mdTabs)

This default behavior can be overridden through the md-stretch-tabs attribute. Here is a table showing when stretching will occur:

**md-stretch-tabs**

use ***always***